# lifetime of pthread_t in constructor of class

Tags: c++, multithreading, lifetime

I'm reading the source code of a project, which is developed with C++98 on Linux.

There is such a piece of code:

```
class Test {
public:
    Test();
    static void func(void *arg) {
        pthread_detach(pthread_self());
        Test *obj = (Test*)arg;
        // do something
    }
};

Test::Test() {
    pthread_t tid; // ???
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, Test::func, this);
}
```

This is quite clear: a thread is created in the constructor of `Test`, which calls the function `func`, and this thread would be detached.

But I'm worrying about `pthread_t tid;`. When the construcor returns, the variable `tid`, as a local variable, should be released. Am I right? However, we have passed its address as the first parameter of `pthread_create`.

Will it cause some lifetime issue, such as a segment fault?

Comment: FWIW, the code wont even compile as you can't pass member functions to `pthread_create`.  Any reason you aren't using a `std::thread`?  If you just wan to launch and detach a thread it's as simple as `std::thread{[this](){ this->function_to_run(); }}.detach();`

Comment: `tid` will go away as soon as the constructor is finished. It's no different from an `int` variable. `pthread_create` simply puts the thread id into `tid`, then you can do whatever yolu want with `tid`, for example ignore it. Read the documentation of `pthread_closely`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Test::func is probably a static function in the original code, in which case it can be passed to pthread_create(). As for your question about std::thread, did you see that the code referenced is from C++98 on Linux, which was before std::thread existed?

Comment: @c.fogelklou  Yes, it's `static`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call pthread_create, it saves the ID of the thread in `tid`.

It doesn't save the address of `tid`. It just puts the ID there before it returns.

So there is no problem.

---

However, if this bothers you, you should call `pthread_detach(tid)` in `Test::Test` instead of `pthread_detach(pthread_self())` inside the thread.

It is *allowed* for a thread to detach itself, but it is slightly strange, because the purpose of `pthread_detach` is to tell the system that nobody is going to wait for this thread (by calling `pthread_join`), so the thread can be destroyed as soon as it finishes. Usually, whoever is *creating* the thread decides whether to wait for it or not - not the thread itself.